# How to hide light object keeping the brightness alive?

Tags: lighting

How can i hide the plane keeping the brightness?
OK i added a plane as emission light source, i dont want the plane to come in my scene, when i hide the plane brightness also disappears.

Comment: For Cycles, in the object's properties panel, go to the Cycles settings, and uncheck camera ray visibility

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You achieve it by removing camera from ray visibility like here

[image]